# Can't wrap my head around accessing fonts on server (getting 404 errors in console)

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, webfonts

So I downloaded a new font called "Alef". It's in hebrew, but that's irrelevant as I'm unable to activate it. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something really stupid but I've been trying for hours to apply it but with no avail.

What I got:

8 files:

4 x normal eot, svg, ttf, woff

4 x bold eot, svg, ttf, woff

And a stylsheet file called stylesheet.css, which now contains the following code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Alef';
src: url("/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-bold.eot");
src: url("/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-bold.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
     url("/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-bold.woff") format('woff'),
     url("/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-bold.ttf") format('truetype'),
     url("/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-bold.svg#alefbold") format('svg');
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;

}
@font-face {
font-family: 'Alef';
src: url("/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-regular.eot");
src: url("/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-regular.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
     url("/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-regular.woff") format('woff'),
     url("/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-regular.ttf") format('truetype'),
     url("/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-regular.svg#alefregular") format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

I have uploaded all files to my theme directory: /wp-content/themes/duet/

My main CSS file is called style.css, which is also in the same directory, I added this code to the file:

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'Alef';
src: url('Alef.eot');
src: url('Alef.eot?#iefix')
   format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('Alef.woff') format('woff'),
   url('Alef.ttf') format('truetype'),
   url('Alef.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}
```

Then what I did, was add this line to my header.php:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/duet/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
```

And of course I set my p {font-family: Alef;)

What am I doing wrong? I'm getting 404 errors for the files in Chrome's console. It shows the CORRECT URL in the right side of the error console though.

Comment: Did you tried with relative paths?

Comment: its probably because you declare it twice and the main.css is the latest. In the main.css you don't have any paths to the files also

Comment: Where do I declare it twice? can you suggest the best way to install? I honestly think I tried every trick. Chrome is telling me there is an 404 but showing the correct path. I'm totally lost.

Comment: I read it like you had both of your stylesheets at the same time. Is this local or production? you might need to add mime types for production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main issues:

- You are referencing 12 different files but you only have 8 (Alef.eot,
  etc.; Alef-regular.eot, etc.; Alef-bold.eot, etc.)
- I think your 2 'src' statements per declaration is messing things up. Should only be one with url's separated by commas.

Here is what I would do:

- Remove the font-face declaration in style.css. Move the font-face declarations out of stylesheet.css and into style.css.
- Only use one 'src' declaration with all url's separated by commas.

Here is the code I would use: (your file paths substituted):

```
`@font-face {
    font-family: 'Alef';
    src: url('/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-regular.svg#Alef') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

ADDITION: Of course, here is bold version...

```
`@font-face {
    font-family: 'Alef';
    src: url('/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-bold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/wp-content/themes/duet/Alef-bold.svg#Alef') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this tool almost obsessively. Saves me the time of working out bugs just like this one.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Best tool ever.